# Fastlane concurrent builds

Tags: android, ruby, multithreading, gradle, fastlane

I'm getting an error in my Fastlane setup when I try to run two build lanes concurrently. Here's the relevant code:

```rb
lane :builds do
    current_directory = Dir.pwd
    google_thread = Thread.new { google_staging(cwd: current_directory) } # Start a thread for google_release
    huawei_thread = Thread.new { huawei_staging(cwd: current_directory) } # Start a thread for huawei_release

    # Wait for both threads to finish
    google_thread.join
    huawei_thread.join
end

lane :google_staging  do |options|
    cwd = options[:cwd]
    increment_version_code(app_project_dir: '**/app', flavor: "staging")

    gradle(
        task: "assemble",
        flavor: "staging",
        build_type: "release"
    )
end

lane :huawei_staging do |options|
    cwd = options[:cwd]
    increment_version_code(app_project_dir: '**/app-hms', flavor: "staging")

    gradle(
        task: "assemble",
        flavor: "staging",
        build_type: "release"
    )
end
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
#<Thread:0x0000557399632cb8 Fastfile:41 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-android_versioning-0.5.5/lib/fastlane/plugin/android_versioning/actions/get_value_from_build.rb:20:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - fast/app/build.gradle (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Comment: Fastlane isn't threadsafe, unfortunately.